# XML validation against an XSD using javax.xml.validation.Validator

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, sax

The xsd contains a declaration like:

```
<xsd:attribute name="IDENTIFIER" use="required" type="xsd:ID" />
```

The line in question within the xml looks like:

```
<HEADER IDENTIFIER="invalidId 01">
```

or

```
<HEADER IDENTIFIER="validId01">
```

The type xsd:ID see also http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/relax-CHP-19.html

defines, colon, space or start with a number is not allowed.
If the generated file is opened within the eclipse ide and validated against the daclared xsd the error is found and signaled correctly.
However, during JUnit test, the same xsd is loaded and the generated file is validated against it. This validation finds any kind of malformed xml, but does not find the invalid attribute IDENTIFIER.

The validation code looks like:

```
static boolean validate(Source source) {
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        Validator validator = mySchema.newValidator();
        success = validate(validator, source);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        logger.info(MSG_BASE + "SAXException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.info(MSG_BASE + "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return success;
}


private static boolean validate(Validator validator, Source source) 
                                                    throws SAXException, IOException {

    ErrorHandler erH = new DefaultHandler2();
    validator.setErrorHandler(erH);
    validator.validate(source);
    return true;
}
```

Does anybody know what is possibly missing to tell the validator to consider the restrictions on attributes?

Instead of using the DefaultHandler2, I setup my own ValidationErrorHandler as:

```
public class ValidationErrorHandler extends DefaultHandler {
```

including:

```
 @Override
public void error (SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
throw new SAXParseException(e.getMessage(), buildLocator(e), e);
```

}

```
private Locator buildLocator(SAXParseException e) {
    Locator2Impl loc = new Locator2Impl();
    loc.setLineNumber(e.getLineNumber());
    loc.setColumnNumber(e.getColumnNumber());
    loc.setSystemId(e.getSystemId());
    loc.setPublicId(e.getPublicId());
    return loc;
}
```

The same for the warning and the FatalError method!
For the moment I have all what I need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that `xsd:ID`s may not contain spaces.

As to why you're not receiving an error from your Java validation code, note that `DefaultHandler2()` ignores all parsing events.  In particular, regarding the [`error()`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#error%28org.xml.sax.SAXParseException%29) method:

> The default implementation does nothing. Application writers may
>   override this method in a subclass to take specific actions for each
>   error, such as inserting the message in a log file or printing it to
>   the console.

In general, in fact, the interface for [**org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler**](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/api/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html) is thus documented:

> **WARNING**: If an application does not register an ErrorHandler, XML
>   parsing errors will go unreported, except that SAXParseExceptions will
>   be thrown for fatal errors. In order to detect validity errors, an
>   ErrorHandler that does something with [error()](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/api/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html#error%28org.xml.sax.SAXParseException%29) calls must be
>   registered.

The [source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xerces/java/trunk/samples/sax/) for the [SAX samples included with Xerces2-J](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/samples-sax.html) provide good examples in this area.  In particular, the [`Counter` class](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xerces/java/trunk/samples/sax/Counter.java?revision=944773&view=markup) shows how to extend `DefaultHandler`.

Comment: Good to know. In fact being new to any kind of discipline, I always start with default settings. Hence I thougth the DefaultHandler2() does the job. Not being the case, I'll implement the necessary.

Comment: @juerg let me know if you have any follow-ups.  If I've helped, I'd appreciate it if you'd [**accept**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Of course, your hint was exactly what I was looking for. So next I’ll extend the DefaultHandler to include the required tests. I have still not yet started. Looking at the DefaultHandler, I must say I don’t have any clue which method is best to override. I’ll start with startElement, where the Attributes are mentioned to see what I get. Or maybe, I must override the error method, or both. Documentation is really terse. So, if you can tell me, either where to start, or where related valuable information exists, your hint can speed up my experience.

Comment: @juerg, I've edited the answer and added links to sample source that shows an example of how to extend `DefaultHandler`.

Comment: Meanwhile I had my self a look into the details. I must say it was almost a no brainer. Infact instead of just doing nothing the implementer of the DefaultHandler could easily have done what I did. In fact, the most normal exception handling, just forwarding the exception information to the caller! I added a snippet to may question.